# Multiple Writes to Same table in Redshift

Tags: locking, blocking, redshift

I have a table in Redshift.

My Application has Multiple Writes/Reads on this Table concurrently.
How I do Make sure Reads won't wait for Writes to Commit/RollBack.

I wanted to know which Lock Mode I need to use in this case.
Please provide if any such behaviour is possible in PostgreSQL so that I will check the relevant Redshift implementation.

Comment: Redshift has a completely different implementation on how data is stored than Postgres. So the reference to Postgres is pretty much useless. You will need to consult the [Redshift manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift_system_overview.html)

Comment: I couldn't get any Official Documentation for Explicit Locks in Red Shift, while the same is available in PostGres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html)